# Creating facebook app with callback url

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am creating a facebook app. And I want to let users to login to my website using it(Using passportjs).

But to do that, I need to give callback url(my website url). But I couldn't find that field in the facebook app creating page.

Am I missing something? I have searched for it for a quite long time.

Comment: Go to Apps-> <name of your app> -> Basic. Then got to "Select how your app integrates with Facebook". Select "Website with Facebook Login". In the field "Site URL" enter the url of your app

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Writing as of Feb 2, 2014 I found these instructions to be current;

1. Go to your app
2. On the left-hand sidebar, click Settings
3. Under the main section, click Add Platform
4. Click 'Website'
5. Specify your callback in the Site URL field (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback)`.

Comment: what happens during deployment to production. do we keep on changing the urls for each one or is there an option for multiple domains?

Comment: Not an expert but afaik you will need to setup two apps? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @user1371896 you will have an `.env` file where you will have a the url

Answer (score 10):

1. Go to your app.
2. On the left-hand sidebar, click Settings.
3. Under the main section, click Add Platform.
4. Click 'Website'.
5. Specify your callback in the Site URL field (e.g. http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback).

Comment: Update your answer as the traffic coming here is being confused. The below answer is the right one now as the facebook developer design/interface has been changed @Stanley

Answer (score 6):

Call back URL must be provided in the Clint O auth settings in order the facebook to send the user credentials and access Token after user logged into facebook through your app. Facebook's developer website UI was changed again. Now the client OAuth settings block was moved into Facebook Login. To provide the callback URL Now the path is

Your App Dashboard > On the Left-hand sidebar > facebook login > Clint Oauth Settings > Valid OAuth redirect URIs

Answer (score 2):

The "Callback URL" is the URL that will be contacted once the user has accepted or rejected the OAuth request.

This is set as a parameter of your OAuth request. So you set the URL in your own program, not somewhere in Facebook.

In Java/Spring social you would do:

```
OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();
params.setRedirectUri("http://yoursite/callback");
```

Once you set this, it must also match a "Valid OAuth Redirect URL" as sivanagaraju's answer mentions, otherwise Facebook will reject it. In the "Facebook Login" tab under your app, enter all valid callback URL's, such as http://localhost/callback, http://productionUrl/callback, etc.

If you don't see "Facebook Login" tab under your app, click "Add Product-> Facebook Login->Get Started" Enter the Valid Callback Urls -> Save changes.

Comment: I have to say, the new flow is pretty obscure. I would never have thought about 'Add Product'

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Facebook developer page.
2. In the left hand side bar, under 'Products' you'll either see or need to add the Facebook Login product.
3. Once you've added it, you can go to Facebook Login settings and add your URL to 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs'